Cancel Installer custom action when Cancel button is pressed in MSVS Installer
I am currently implementing an MSI installer using the Visual Studio Installer project extension. I use custom actions to extend its functionality and install some 3rd party packages that are required. These packages (which are quite large in some cases) are just installed one after another in the Install method. The problem I have is that when those packages are being installed and the installation is canceled from the Cancel button in the MSI installation window, I cannot find a way to know from the custom action that the installation has been canceled and it keeps installing all 3rd party packages till the end. Only once it has finished with all the packages, the Rollback method is invoked but it's a bit late. I would like to be able to know that the user has canceled the installation at least after each package has been installed, provided no abort exception (or similar) will be thrown. Is there a way?
Something like:
[RunInstaller(true)]
public class MyCustomActions: Installer
{
  public override void Install(IDictionary savedState)
  {
     //Installing package 1
     
     //Check installation canceled

     //Installing package 2

     //Check installation canceled

     //so on
  }
}


I had a look at the Parent property and the Context property in the base class but could not find anything helpful.
I have also seen that you can disable the Cancel button  but I prefer it to stay active.
